# javascript XMLHTTPRequest returning null in firefox

Tags: javascript, xml, firefox, typeerror

I have a website I'm coding that is supposed to grab some XML from an external site and parse it, but it's giving me a typeError: xmlDoc is null. Not sure what's wrong and I was wondering if anyone could help.

Here's teh code:

EDIT: added changes

```
        function loadXML()
    {

        var XMLHttpRequestObject = false;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            XMLHttpRequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
            XMLHttpRequestObject.overrideMimeType("text/xml");
            console.log("XML HTTP Request, xml override.");

        }
         else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            XMLHttpRequestObject = new
            ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            console.log("ActiveXObject xml request.");
        }

        if(XMLHttpRequestObject) {
            XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET", xmlLink, true);

            XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4) {
                // Load complete
                var xmlDocument = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseXML;
                parseXML(xmlDocument);
              }
            };

            XMLHttpRequestObject.send(null);
        }
    }

    function parseXML(xmlDoc){
        console.log(xmlDoc);
        var test1 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('icon');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox complies with the Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) specification. Unless the external site in question is explicitly allowing * (all origins) you'll need to follow the tutorial at:
https://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors/

Answer (score 0):

```
XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET", xmlLink, true);
```

So this sets up an async request but doesn't actually send it yet.

```
var xmlDocument = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseXML;
```

and this asks for the document that's the result of doing the request and parsing the resulting string as XML.  Which of course doesn't exist yet, since the request hasn't happened.

You want something like this:

```
XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET", xmlLink, true);
XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4) {
    // Load complete
    var xmlDocument = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseXML;
    parseXML(xmlDocument);
  }
};
XMLHttpRequestObject.send();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm still learning javascript so some of this is confusing for me. I added the changes but I'm still getting type Null responses in the console, not sure what's up. I've updated the code above.

Comment: @ShadowVariable That should work.  Do you have a link to a site showing the problem, by any chance?